# Find out if an array has the integer '6' in its first or last position

Tags: java, arrays

This is the method I'm using to find out if the first or last integer is 6

```
public Boolean firstLast6(int[] a[]){
        int size = a.length;
        int x = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if ((a[i] == 6)&&((i != 0) || (i != size - 1)))
                x = 1;
        }
        if (x == 1){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

this is my main, where the problem is occurring I think

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Numbers with Space: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] arr = scan.readLine().split(" ");//take the input in string array separated by whitespaces" "
        int [] intArr = new int[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            intArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);//each array indices parsed to integer
        }
        Boolean ans = firstLast6(intArr);
        if (ans == true){
            System.out.println("6 is in the first or last position");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("6 is not in the first or last position");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `int[] a[]` just a typo? Because if it isn't, you should probably remove the second set of brackets. Also, can't you just see if `a[0]` or `a[a.length - 1]` are equal to 6?

Comment: Also, please use `boolean` (lowercase). `Boolean` is a wrapper, and you should only use it when you have to use objects instead of primitives, like when you're using a generic method.

Comment: Side note: I just learned that `int[] a[]` is equivalent to `int[][] a`.

Comment: @andrewjames The compiler should really raise an error about that. It's bad enough putting square brackets after the variable name C-style, but mixing both ways is the perfect recipe for disaster :)

Comment: @user - totally agree - hence my surprise. (It's in the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2): _The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, *or both*._ emphasis mine).

Comment: @andrewjames It kinda makes sense now. I didn't realize you could use that to declare multiple arrays of different dimensions on the same line, although I still don't understand why anyone would want to do that

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a loop to check last and first index of the array.

```
public boolean firstLast6(int[] a){
    return a[0] == 6 || a[a.length - 1] == 6;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yousaf's answer is correct. However:

1. firstLast6 has to be static to be called in main, or you have to create an instance of your class.
2. If you don't specify array size, you should read it into a String array, and then parse each element in it with `Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);`, and add it to your int array:

   ```
   String[] arr = scan.nextLine().split(" "); // String array (where your input goes)
   int[] nums = new int[arr.length]; // int array, where parsed integers will be stored
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) // parsing each String and assigning it to int array
       nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
   ```

Here's the whole code that you can use:

```
   public static Boolean firstLast6(int[] a) {
    return a[0] == 6 || a[a.length - 1] == 6;
   }

 public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter Numbers with Space: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] arr = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
    int[] nums = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
    }
    
    Boolean ans = firstLast6(nums);
    if (ans == true){
        System.out.println("6 is in the first or last position");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("6 is not in the first or last position");
    }
 }
```